# Linq: List all Rows in DataGridView that contain at least 2 cells with a Value

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter all rows in a DataGridView that contain at least two Cells with a specific value, but starting at third column.

What I have:

```
var filteredRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows) {
    if (row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(x => x.ColumnIndex > 1 && x.Value != null && (int)x.Value == 10).Count() >= 2) {
        filteredRows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

I'd like to have the whole thing in Linq syntax.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: What issue's if any are you having?

Comment: None. The lines above work fine. I just want to learn how to process the whole thing (if possible) with Linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___):

```
myDataGridView.Rows.SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(x => x.ColumnIndex > 1 && x.Value != null && (int)x.Value == 10).Count() >= 2))
```

Comment: Thenk you for your answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work using .NET 4.5. myDataGridView.Rows doesn't know SelectMany(). I even tried myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().SelectMany(...) but then I get the error: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: That error means you need to specify the generic arguments after SelectMany, which would likely be `<DataGridViewCell, DataGridViewCell>` as both your collection type and result type are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a where instead of a if

```
myDataGridView.Rows
  .where(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
               .Count(x => 
                            x.ColumnIndex > 1 &&
                            x.Value != null &&
                            (int)x.Value ==10) >= 2
        ).ToList();
```